# Receiving "bad character range" error from Google Cloud SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

so I'm trying to add automatic backups to my minecraft server and I'm using a bash script that auto saves the world and puts it in cloud storage. Whenever I run the script, I get this error:

raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range

I have installed Python 3 after hearing that it is a Python 2.7 problem and the script runs 2.7 anyways with the same error.

Python versions: 2.7.13 (used) and 3.5.3. Debian Linux

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -r mcs -X stuff '/save-all\n/save-off\n'
/usr/bin/gsutil cp -R ${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/world gs://[terits-smp-minecraft-minecraft-backup]/$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")-world
screen -r mcs -X stuff '/save-on\n'
```

The full debug log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil", line 21, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil.py", line 124, in RunMain
    sys.exit(gslib.__main__.main())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 433, in main
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 762, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    _HandleUnknownFailure(e)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 628, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 411, in RunNamedCommand
    return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 1162, in RunCommand
    copy_helper_opts.daisy_chain,
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/name_expansion.py", line 650, in __init__
    name_expansion_dest_tuple = next(self.name_expansion_dest_iter)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 1093, in _ConstructNameExpansionIteratorDstTupleIterator
    logger=self.logger))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 1419, in ExpandUrlToSingleBlr
    logger=logger))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py", line 161, in __iter__
    for bucket_listing_ref in self._ExpandBucketWildcards(bucket_fields=['id']):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py", line 389, in _ExpandBucketWildcards
    prog = re.compile(regex)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

I have been using this guide so far to help me since I am not too savvy with google cloud:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server#schedule_backups

Comment: What are the values of `error` and `v` here?

Comment: What will "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}" evaluate to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error `raise error, v # invalid expression` is triggered by gsutil. This is triggered because you are not following the [object naming rules](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming)

This part is invalid `$(date "+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")` because you are using wildcards characters which are being taken literally by gsutil and you are also leaving a space in the name which isn't accepted.

I suggest you get the date and time in another step of your batch and then add it directly as a String to the gsutil command.